# Remove aria-disabled from filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

When I choose model in filter, all brands are hidden except one which is true brand for this model. For example if I choose model `Duster` - I can only select brand `Dacia`. All other brands have attribute `aria-disabled="true"`. So true brand looks like

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-make-l3-result-6exf-dacia" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
Dacia</li>
```

and other brand

```
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-make-l3-result-t0ia-citroen" role="treeitem" aria-disabled="true">
Citroen</li>
```

How can I make site show all brands when I choose model?

Comment: Can you share what you already tried and the rest of the HTML ?

Comment: please take a look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp if you want to change the value of the attribute `aria-disabled`